# How to limited related post show in flatsome theme Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post

my wordpress theme show all related post after a post, how can i limited them in a specific number, such as 3? I can not find it in dashboard.
This is single.php but i have no idea about php.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="article-inner <?php flatsome_blog_article_classes(); ?>">
        <?php
            if(flatsome_option('blog_post_style') == 'default' || flatsome_option('blog_post_style') == 'inline'){
                get_template_part('template-parts/posts/partials/entry-header', flatsome_option('blog_posts_header_style') );
            }
        ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts/content', 'single' ); ?>
    </div>
</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks for your help.

I tried some code in code snippets plugin but it's not work.